# Implement onTaskRemoved() in IntentService for API level below 14

Tags: android

I want to implement onTaskRemoved in IntentService to cancel some notifications if the user swipe his app from Recent apps. How can I do it for devices with API level below 14 as it supports 14 and above?

Solved: It was

```
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
```

which can't be called for API levels below 14. So, I removed the statement. It works fine now.

Comment: @MarekDovina I don't understand how it will help me.

Comment: @MarekDovina I found the solution. It was   super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 which I can't call inside onTaskRemoved for API Level below 14. I just removed the statement and it works fine now.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding.